# Позиционирование слоёв в CSS

Tags: html, css3, html5

Прошу помочь, не могу разобраться с позиционированием слоев.

```css
.testimonials {
  background-color: #fff;
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=testimonials') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

.testi {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.testi h3 {
  color: #ddc372;
}

.testi h3::after {
  content: '';
  width: 160px;
  height: 3px;
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ffff/555555?text=testi-h3::after') no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
}

.testimonials::before {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 450px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #010f16;
  opacity: .6;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper-testimonials .slides {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
}

.wrapper-testimonials h5 {
  color: #000;
}

.wrapper-testimonials h5::after {
  content: '_________';
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 10px auto 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="container-fluid testimonials">
  <div class="container testi">
    <h3>Отзывы о Нас</h3>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row text-center wrapper-testimonials">
      <div class="flex-fill slides">
        <h5>Тимур Жумашев</h5>
        <p>Заказывал чистку дивана и двух стульев. Реята приехали оперативно, почистили "на совесть", а также проконсультировали в части дальнейшего ухода за моей мебелью</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-fill slides">
        <h5>Тимур Жумашев</h5>
        <p>Заказывал чистку дивана и двух стульев. Реята приехали оперативно, почистили "на совесть", а также проконсультировали в части дальнейшего ухода за моей мебелью</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-fill slides">
        <h5>Тимур Жумашев</h5>
        <p>Заказывал чистку дивана и двух стульев. Реята приехали оперативно, почистили "на совесть", а также проконсультировали в части дальнейшего ухода за моей мебелью</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

На вложенность и названия элементов прошу не обращать внимания, хочу в дальнейшем написать для всего этого "слайдер".

Вводная информация:

1. Есть фон (`background`, задан к секции `testimonials`)
2. Есть прозрачный слой (задан через псевдоэлемент `::before`)
3. Есть блок с основным контентом (`.testi`)

Проблемы:

1. Пытался задать к `.testimonials` и к `.testimonials::before z-index: -2` и `-1` соответственно, а для `.testi 999`.
   **Результат** визуально всё в порядке, но, при ПКМ - Исследовать элемент к первому блоку slides - кидает на тег `body`. Это применяется к 1 и 2 блоку с классом `.slides`, к третьему же Инспектор отправляет корректно.
   При этом, текст в первых двух блоках не выделяется, ощущение, что поверх первых двух блоков висит какой-то прозрачный фон...
2. Убрал `z-index` у `.testimonials` и `.testimonials::before`, оставил у `.testi z-index: 999`.
   **Результат** блоки с классом `.slides` отображаются корректно, но `h3` внутри `.testi`, у которого по логике самый высокий `z-index`, ушел под слой `testimonials::before`.
   При этом проблем с выделением и инспектированием элементов нет, т.е. так называемой "прозрачной" заглушки нету.

Скрин:
[image: Фото]

Надеюсь, я корректно изложил проблему. Спасибо!

Comment: Если вы устанавливаете элементу отрицательный *z-index*, он будет находится позади **ВСЕХ** элементов, а не только элементов родителя. Это к вашей первой проблеме.

Comment: Увы, `z-index` работает не так, как хотелось бы.. Как сказал knowsOut, `z-index: -1` означает не "на уровень ниже текущего "слоя""..

Comment: А каков должен быть конечный результат?

Comment: Не должно быть проблем, описанных выше)
То есть слои должны располагаться таким образом:

1. background-image
2. прозрачный фон
3. контент

У меня 2 проблемы вылезает, я их описал, не могу сообразить, почему это происходит(

Comment: Добавленный html и css не выдает описанных проблем. Для решения проблемы с позиционированием нужно: 1) добавить стили и html слайдера, о котором идет речь 2) желательно пояснить для чего все эти манипуляции с z-index, так как возможно можно обойтись и без его использования.